# Transform map values in Jenkins Pipeline groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `LinkedList` in which I want to change all values. With the array I can do simply:

```
arr = arr.collect { arr -> transformFunction(arr) }
```

But with the `LinkedList`:

```
list = list.collect { key, val -> [(key): transformFunction(val)] }
```

But this doesn't work unfortunately (at least in the pipeline). What is the correct way to do this in groovy?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean a `Map` and not a `List`.  So if you want to transform the values, then `each` is good for side effects:

```
notalist.each { k,v -> list[k] = transformFunction(v) }
```

Or you can create a copy with `collectEntries`:

```
newmap = map.collectEntries{ k, v -> [k, transformFunction(v)] }
```